# C macro building functions

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to cut down on some typing using the preprocessor. I am trying to define 2 or more function-like objects (inline functions or macros, not too bothered) using a single macro:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define gen(name0, name1, mask, offset)         \
  inline unsigned char #name0(config) {return (config & mask) << offset));}     \
  inline unsigned char #name1(config) {return ((config & (mask << offset)) >> offset);}

gen (clk_option_write, clk_option_read, 0x07, 1) 
// I would like this to generate functions:
// inline unsigned char clk_option_write(unsigned char config) {return (config & 0x07) << 1));}
// inline unsigned char clk_option_read(unsigned char config) {return ((config & (0x07 << 1)) >> 1);}
// or something that generated macros would do:
// #define clk_option_write(config) ((config & 0x07) << 1)
// #define clk_option_read(config) (((config & (0x07 << 1)) >> 1)

int main (void)
{
  char test = 0;
  test = (clk_option_write(2));
  printf("%d", clk_option_read(test));
}
```

This doesnt compile but it hopefully gives you an idea of what I would like to acheve. I was wondering if there is annother way to get the same effect? (without resorting to a pre-preprocessor)

Comment: "I'm trying to cut down on some typing using the preprocessor" As a rule of thumb, that's almost certainly a very bad idea. Apart from that, I have no idea what you are trying to do. There is no relation between the icky macros and the main program.

Comment: yes you're right, I edited it so it makes "slightly" more sense...

Comment: If it doesn't compile, what is the compiler's error message?

Comment: Not sure how relavant this is, that example is fundemantally flawed and purely to demonstrate an idea, but: test.c:7: error: expected identifier or '(' before string constant

Comment: Look at the output of the pre-processor (`-E` flag for GCC and clang). As it is there's an obvious unbalanced `(` in your main, please at least clean that up.

Comment: Don't run the preprocessor output, it's C code! Edit that file (with your favorite text editor) and check it for syntax problems.

Comment: You haven't even compiled the code.  The option `-E` runs the preprocessor.  My 'answer' is to type `cat test` and look at the output.  Then run gcc test.c to try and compile.  Maybe then come back if you still have problems

Comment: gotcha thanks, I dont think I explained this very well. The above is just a demo, compiling it is pointless, it wont work, I know why it wont work, its just to try and demonstrate the effect I am trying to acheve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that what you are trying to achieve is to create an API that is simple to use. And you want to be able to easily change the various function's behavior at compile time.

The proper approach is to use object-oriented design and create a "code module" for this (call it "code module", ADT, class or whatever you like).

// clk.h

```
#ifndef CLK_H
#define CLK_H

#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t clk_option_write (uint8_t config);
uint8_t clk_option_read  (uint8_t config);

#endif
```

// clk.c

```
static const uint8_t MASK   = 0x07;
static const uint8_t OFFSET = 1;

uint8_t clk_option_write (uint8_t config)
{
  return (config & MASK) << OFFSET;
}


uint8_t clk_option_read  (uint8_t config)
{
  return ( (config & (MASK << OFFSET) >> OFFSET);
}
```

---

As for why I gave the above answer:

> I'm trying to cut down on some typing

Usually a bad idea. Programming is all about typing text. If you don't like typing a lot of text, or if you do so very slowly, you might want to consider another career.

There are of course lots of smart tricks to avoid repetitive typing: use copy/paste, use external scripts, use a clever text editor or even MS Excel. None of these tricks involve obfuscating your program's source code.

> ...using the preprocessor

Usually a bad idea. The pre-processor has non-existent type safety and function-like macros are very hard to read, debug and maintain. This is well-known and therefore function-like macros should only be used as the very last resort.

> I'm trying to cut down on some typing using the preprocessor.

Combining two bad ideas results in a very bad idea. Apart from the things mentioned, you can expect other people who read your code (including yourself, 1 year later) to know the C language. You cannot expect them to know the unique, home-brewed, macro language. Strive to make programs that are simple, easy to read and easy to maintain.

Comment: yep, this is great, but... I would like to make 245 of them with different names/values.

Comment: @jayjay Updated answer. The solution is almost certainly _not_ function-like macros...

Comment: @jayjay if you have that much boiler plate code then ask yourself 2 questions:(1) am I doing this the wrong way and can I have a function that behaves differently based on the input rather than 245 functions and (2) should I generate the C file automatically (using your favourite scripting language)

Comment: (2) should I generate the C file automatically <-- I think this is the way forward, as its for an api for an embedded system I would like to avoid the the extra function call assosiated with (1), thanks for your help.

Comment: -1. The content of this answer below the line is *objectively wrong*, and awful. Programming is not about typing, it's about expression (a good programmer is a lazy programmer); there are plenty of concise *and* perfectly readable languages out there; there are plenty of safe and even type-safe macro systems; and suggesting "use any scripting language as long as it's not CPP" is *religion*, not engineering (oh but it's suddenly not obfuscation if a different engine does it?). The design flaws of C are neither universal truths nor poisons that corrupt everything they touch.